# How do I change the default branch for a large number of github repositories?

Tags: git, github

I have a large number of repositories and I want to change the default branch from one branch to another.  Yeah, I can do it using the web UI, but it would be nice if I could do it in a script.  Possible?

UPDATE:

No way to do this, according to github support. I've asked them to add the ability to change the default branch to the API. That would obviously be the best way.